# ZK : Using a custom Id generator for selenium while having dynamic ids

Tags: selenium, zk

I'm using a custom Id generator, [the one listed here in the article](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2013/July/ZK_Testing_with_Selenium_IDE)

It works fine, however I've dynamic ID that i generate for my tabs:

```
<tabpanels children="@load(vm.myTabsList) @template('myTemplate')" >
    <template name="myTemplate" var="each">
        <tabpanel id="tabPanel${each.key}">
            <include src="zul/myTabZul.zul/>
        </tabpanel>
    </template>
</tabpanels>
```

I'm getting this exception :

```
org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException: Illegal character, }, not allowed in uuid,
```

The method that throws Error doesn't leave much room actualy ... Not sure how I can bypass that.

```
public static void checkUuid(String uuid) {
    int j;
    if (uuid == null || (j = uuid.length()) == 0)
        throw new UiException("uuid cannot be null or empty");

    while (--j >= 0) {
        final char cc = uuid.charAt(j);
        if ((cc < 'a' || cc > 'z') && (cc < 'A' || cc > 'Z')
        && (cc < '0' || cc > '9') && cc != '_')
            throw new UiException("Illegal character, "+cc+", not allowed in uuid, "+uuid);
    }
}
```

Although the original generator seems to do just fine but it probably doesn't generate the Id at the same time.

If someone has expering on selenium and ZK, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's Selenium related.

The final '}' is considered part of your id string because 'tabPanel${each.key}' is not a valid EL expression. Have a look [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/Data_Binding/EL_Expression) on how to write valid EL expressions.
I would advise you to concatenate the two parts (tabPanel and ${each.key}) using the core's cat method. Your code would become:

```
<!-- at the beginning of your file -->
<?taglib uri="http://www.zkoss.org/dsp/web/core" prefix="c"?>
...
<tabpanel id="${c:cat('tabPanel',each.key)}">
```

'each.key' will be properly interpreted thanks to the surrounding ${.} (it does not have to be in direct contact).

I hope this is not too late and it still helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you try to use a dynamic id, but it doesn't take it.

`tabPanel${each.key}` contains the '}' spoke of (and mark up that they check from right to left, so that's the first one we come across)

With a little more of the zul I could advise how you can change it.

Comment: Yep that's because of the dynamic ID, otherwise it works fine.

But i use those afterward so i need to keep it that way.
Added a bit more code in my original question.